# How to connect to a remote socket in docker/engine-api?

Tags: go, docker, virtualization, docker-compose, docker-registry

I want to retrieve all docker images of a remote machine, so I am using docker/engine-api: https://github.com/docker/engine-api

I was successful in returning the docker images of my local machine
with the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/docker/engine-api/client"
    "github.com/docker/engine-api/types"
    "golang.org/x/net/context"
)

func main() {
    defaultHeaders := map[string]string{"User-Agent": "engine-api-cli-1.0"}
    cli, err := client.NewClient("unix:///var/run/docker.sock", "v1.22", nil, defaultHeaders)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    options := types.ContainerListOptions{All: true}
    containers, err := cli.ContainerList(context.Background(), options)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, c := range containers {
        fmt.Println(c.ID)
    }
}
```

But now does anybody know how can I retrieve the docker images of a remote machine given its address,username, and password

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That kind of Unix socket is only accessible through proccesses in the same machine.

To access your docker from a remote machine you need to run it with a special configuration to run over ip.

This configuration is `DOCKER_OPTS="-H <ip_address>:<port>"`  (or `-H 0.0.0.0:<port>` if you whant it to listen on all interfaces), and it depends the version you are running of docker where you must configure it.

[Here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/) you can find more information on where to configure DOCKER_OPTS depending on the operation system version.

Hope it helps!